# Shiny app opens and closes immediately

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am getting this error when trying to run shiny application.This makes the  app open and close immediately.

**The error I get is:**

```
Warning: Error in server: unused arguments (input = list(impl = <environment>, readonly = TRUE, ns = function (x) 
x), output = list(impl = <environment>, ns = function (x) 
x))
Stack trace (innermost first):
    45: server
     4: <Anonymous>
     3: do.call
     2: print.shiny.appobj
     1: <Promise>
Error in server(...) : 
  unused arguments (input = list(impl = <environment>, readonly = TRUE, ns = function (x) 
x), output = list(impl = <environment>, ns = function (x) 
x))
```

I don't why is this error occurring.

The app is one of the example apps stored in shiny apps.

Comment: In the `server.ui` file, make sure that the line lines in the file are those defining [the server function to be run](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/app-formats.html).

Answer (score 1):

Issue is in your server calling function. shinyApp() function is not getting server.

For Example:

1. serverShiny <- (function(input, output) {}
2. server <- (function(input, output) {}

so according to the call of shinyapp() 2nd is right because it is passing the right name

```
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

It worked for me. Same Error. Hope it will work for you